# query against a reference table returns fewer records than it should

Tags: mysql

Here are the 2 tables that I am using: http://pastie.org/4539541

The table products_options_values is the reference table and the products_images table is the table I want to compare against the reference table.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
select
products_options_values_name
from 
products_options_values as pov
inner join
products_images as img
on pov.products_options_values_id = img.color_id
where img.products_id = '426'
```

This only returns 1 record, but when I do this query:

```
select color_id from products_images where products_id = '426'
```

It returns 2 records.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing the query wrong but I don't know how else I should do it.
I know the color_id name in products_images and the products_options_values_id in products_options_values should be the same column name but I can't change it because it will cause massive amounts of errors in the application Im working in.

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: how many rows you get by Select products_options_values_name
from products_options_values where products_options_values_id = '426' Are you getting more than 1 record?

Comment: Have you tried a `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: yes i have , i got the same result

Comment: products_options_values is a reference table for the column color_id in products_images. that query against products_options_values is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Using Right Join with COALESCE would help you.

Comment: whats the difference between right join, left join, and inner join?

Comment: Question already answered on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-full-join-in-mys)

Answer (score 0):

A few things I want to give you feedback on:

1. You're using MyISAM tables for what should be a relational database. MyISAM does not support relationships through foreign keys, which protect the referential integrity of your database. Without foreign keys you cannot guarantee that the tables which reference others (in the cases of your join tables) will reflect actual values in your database. Instead use Innodb.
2. You should not use quotes on numeric values, '1' means the character 1, not 1 as in the integer. Although MySQL is generally lenient about this, it's still incorrect.
3. MyISAM only has table level locks. Any operation that requires a lock will lock the whole table for writing. This causes concurrency issues.
4. Color ID should reference another table that enumerates your colors, and the color ID column should be an integer to reflect that.
5. If you expect that each product image should be only one color, then you should put a unique identifier on it.
6. In your where clause you should specify which table's products_id column you mean.

Comment: #6 sorry about missing that i added it., products_id only exists in products_images.